# IRB crashing with unicode

Tags: ruby, irb

I have a very weird problem with Ruby version 2.6.5p114 in Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
OS Version: 10.0.18363 N/A Build 18363.
When i insert a Unicode character in Greek lets say i try this

```
browser.input(:value => "Εκτύπωση").click
```

Instead of the usual response, the cmd just crashes and powershell gives [process exited with code 1] and becomes unresponsive.

Does anyone know how to fix this. I have tried installing and uninstalling i have change the unicode that the Windows uses but no luck.
Thanks for your time

Comment: What result do you get in IRB for `Encoding.default_external`? Have you tried a different Ruby version?

Comment: Not an answer but Windows 10 allows linux as a sub system (you can use the ubuntu app) I have found that this has avoided more than 90% of the windows based issues I was previously experiencing.

Comment: Encoding is set to #<Encoding:UTF-8>. I think this is correct. Yes I have tried to change the version but no luck. I cannot use subsystem because of the scrapping i do.

Comment: @user520841 you can use a sub system no matter what you are using it for I have built multiple web and file system scrapers without issue. Using ruby directly on windows especially very new versions will have issues and there is literally nothing you can do about it. You could try downgrading to a slightly older version if you'd prefer but I would sincerely recommend installing a Linux sub system and learning how to use it because it will help you drastically in the long run.

Comment: @engineersmnky so i can manifest a chrome driver and work around??? The problem is that my scrapping cant be done in headless mode.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/danwhitston/5cea26ae0861ce1520695cff3c2c3315 sure can

Comment: Thats really impressive (and it beats the purpose of wls but who cares). Although i found the --noreadline that made it all work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems i figured out something. 
If you start the irb with the noreadline switch everything is fixed.

```
irb --noreadline
```

Does anyone know why this is happening??

Comment: no solution, but same problem here. I thought is was due to Ruby 3.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem still plaguing me (irb on command prompt on windows 10 and ruby 2.7.2).
'irb --noreadline' doesn't help.  I can type characters, but I can't paste anything with accented characters. Same problem with irb on Powershell 7.

Comment: This doesn't look like answer. Create a new question if suggestion solution doesn't work for you